# ListView webpart Customization in designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view

I want to insert a list view webpart in a page. As of now i am able to do all the customizations through designer except one i.e. disabling row selection.

All i want is the user should not be able to view document and library setting in the ribbon and for that i have to disable selection of row.

So how can i disable selection???

Thanks in Advance
Alam

Comment: Basically i don't want to show library tools Tab in the ribbon..I know some tweaks in the UI will do it but i am not able to find out that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open web part properties and set **selected view** to **summary view** also you can try to set **toolbar type** to **no toolbar**.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the reply...
after setting to summary view i am still able to see documents and library settings in ribbon when click inside webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this approach (assuming you could deploy a solution package - even Sandbox should be fine):

1. Create your own Content type based on Document. No need to actually
   add aditional properties. Add this content type to your library and
   remove the default Document.
2. Create a Custom Action feature which is targetting Content Types (using RegistrationType and RegistrationId attributes) and hides respective actions (to identify the actual location and Id of the Settings check this file on physical SharePoint server C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML see here an example http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=778). As a result every time you use the XSLTListView in any page the same would apply for your library and buttons would get hidden. Of course, savvy users could always target the Library Settings application page, unless you actually use Permissions to restrict that.